# No visible interface for nsmutabledictionary declares the selector setobject:forkey:

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

Can anyone point out why am i receiving the compile error for

```
[objToSend setObject:self.pathidEdit forkey:@"PathId"];
[objToSend setObject:indexData forkey:@"data"];
```

in the following code?

```
NSMutableArray *indexData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSMutableDictionary *objToSend = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        for(int i=0;i<myPathvideoArray.count;i++)
        {


        NSString *vId=[[myPathvideoArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"videoId"];
    NSNumber *indexNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1];

            [dict setObject:vId forKey: @"VideoId"];

            [dict setObject:indexNum forKey: @"index"];

            [indexData addObject:dict];



        }

        [objToSend setObject:self.pathidEdit forkey:@"PathId"];
        [objToSend setObject:indexData forkey:@"data"];
```

Comment: myPathvideoArray is array of dictionaries ?

Comment: nevermind the k for "forKey" was in small caps... :D Thanks...lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C is case sensitive:

This is correct:

```
[dict setObject:object forKey:key];
```

while this is not:

```
[dict setObject:object forkey:key];
```

Comment: HI All,I am really sorry for having posted such a silly question but my account has been downvoted since then and I cant ask questions anymore.If someone could please upvote it back . I will make sure I dont post minor questions like these again!! Thanks a lot! Sorry about the question again!